# recycleview not showing the last item with AppBarLayout combination

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, recyclerview-layout

When i open this sample app, i want `RecycleView` to show the last item on the list.

In this .gif examle bellow, i have 200 items but, when i open app, its not showing the last item.
`AppBarLayout`/`CollapsingToolbar` push down RecycleView so its not showing the last item.

[image]

this is how i set up RecycleView:

```
mRecyclerChat = findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerChat.setLayoutManager(manager);
        mAdapterChat = new AdapterChat(this, messagesList);
        mRecyclerChat.setAdapter(mAdapterChat);

        //move to the last item in recycleview
        mRecyclerChat.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(mAdapterChat.getMessagesObekt().size() - 1);
```

I have find that i can show last item if i get list size and then use `scrollToPosition()`. I have try that like this.
`mRecyclerChat.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(mAdapterChat.getMessagesObekt().size() - 1);`

However, it looks like `AppBarLayout` push down the whole recycle view.

This is the whole XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/beachcroatia" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagButtonDrag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drag"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messages_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#E1F5FE"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="453dp">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_messageBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:hint="Enter a message" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messages_sendArrow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_message_" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

I think that the problem is `AppBarLayout` who push down the whole `Recycleiew` and the amount of space `AppBarLayout` take, is the number of `RecycleView` items that missing.
If i disable `AppBarLayout` (by collapsing it when app start), everything is fine.

Comment: add paddingBottom="40dp" to recylerview because bottom view hided the reclecer view last item

Comment: I already try, if i add padding bottom then i have free space between RecycleView and edit text on bottom. I know what you mean, but that is not the case. Last item is visible when apbarlayout is collapsed. Somehow AppBarLayout push down the whole ReycleView.

Comment: I thinks scroll of that recyclerview has already reached the bottom, and it cannot further scroll, can you try using scrollToBottom (recyclerView.scrollToPosition(items.size() - 1))  and check

Comment: i already use this line in my code like this.        `mRecyclerChat.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(mAdapterChat.getMessagesObekt().size() - 1);` now i try this instead         `mRecyclerChat.scrollToPosition(mAdapterChat.getMessagesObekt().size() - 1);`
 and still nothing

Comment: Also, if  i start app and set up AppBarLayout to be collapsed, then it is scrolled to the last item on the list. Like i said, i think that  when AppBarLayout is extended, he push down the whole RecycleView. And yes, recycleview is scrolled to the last itme but, AppBarLayout push down the whole RecycleView down and that is why last 10, 15 items are not visibale.